# What purpose does Han's vest back pockets serve?

Tags: star-wars

Han Solo's black vest has what look like four pockets on the top of its back.  That seems somewhat unpractical, because those pockets are hard to reach without removing the vest.  In the spirit of the older question ["What purpose does Chewbacca's belt serve?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17482/4918), what does Han have in his pocketses?

[image: (screencap of Han from the back)]

Han wears this same black vest for example in *The New Hope* when he bargains with Jabba, and in *The Jedi Returns* when he fights on the forest moon of Endor.

(This question was [originally asked by Knick](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=159787#159787) in the context of the Darths & Droids universe, but my question is about the Star Wars films.  Thanks to Valorum, who provided the screen cap above.)

Comment: Better pic here; https://bamfstyle.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/hansolo-cl4c-vest2.jpg?w=664&h=282

Comment: Just as complete speculation, I'd guess they're pockets for armor plating. Someone like Han should be worried about getting shot in the back.

Comment: More likely just more utility pockets.

Comment: The four across the top appear to have holes underneath as well as on top, so they likely serve as sheaths for weapons or tools of some sort.  If the larger pocket below were intended for something like a portable computer (remember - 70's) or a large battery pack for a heavy weapon of some kind, then perhaps the smaller "sheaths" are for keeping cables/wires leading to headgear or accessories organized.  This is all hypothetical, of course, as we never see Han using the pockets for this or anything else, but I suppose he could have "appropriated" the vest from somewhere/someone else. ;)

Comment: pockets are better than postage stamps for storing weapons on your back

Comment: Some kind of [MOLLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOLLE) system?

Comment: Its for energy gels, Han is an avid triathlete

Comment: They are pads so that when you get slammed against the wall it doesn't hurt as much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Extra ammo and supplies**

According to [*The Ultimate Guide to Vintage Star Wars Action figures 1977-1985*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2VaYCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Corellian+spacer+black+vest&source=bl&ots=8EjEZFLRzT&sig=WoFLfYGSoWnk7svMiG9CaOK4hnw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7sNCmsNbRAhWQHsAKHd8vB1UQ6AEITDAO#v=onepage&q=Corellian%20spacer%20black%20vest&f=false), Han is:

> Wearing his Corellian spacer black vest - an article of clothing donned by Corellian mariners which is outfitted with extra pockets to hold extra ammunition and supplies...

Comment: It makes a lot of sense that it would be for spare things he MIGHT need to have, but doesn't have immediate need for: extra-extra ammunition, first-aid kit, space blanket, etc. Most of the time, I'd imagine the pockets are empty, but when a potentially off-the-grid operation comes up, he can fill them up. Being on the back balances some of the load.

Answer (score -3):

I agree that it is most likely for armor plating, however there is also the possibility of it being an point of attachment for a harness. He is a smuggler involved in high speed chases where a harness may help to keep him in place so that he can focus on piloting the Falcon.

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer... and its kind of absurd. Harnesses are usually made to be fitted and removed by the person wearing them. It would be difficult, if not impossible, for a person to work a harness that attached to the back of a vest like that.

Comment: It's for a harness but he is wearing it backwards like Kris Kross.

Comment: All we can do is guess, there is no canon answer.