# What does the First Order Heavy Gunner have on his chest?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, costume, stormtroopers, first-order

When I saw *The Force Awakens*, I had some doubts about the new Stormtrooper design, but the variant I liked the most was the 'Heavy Gunner' (see image below).

However, what I quickly noticed was that the things on his chest, which I had assumed were spare magazines, didn't seem to match up with any of the guns the Stormtroopers use. Plus, the boxes are so smooth, I don't see how they could be used for ammunition unless the important bits are facing downwards (and even then, how do you grip them?).

So, since [this question about Chewbacca's chest boxes got an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/what-purpose-does-chewbaccas-belt-serve), I thought I'd ask about these chest boxes here. What are they, what are they used for, if they are magazines what guns do they fit into?

[image: Now with 100% more hand-drawn circles!]

Comment: I found your lack of circles...disturbing

Comment: @JasonBaker Only a Sith deals in MS Paint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [*The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary*](https://www.dk.com/us/9781465438164-star-wars-the-force-awakens-visual-dictionary/), they indeed hold ammo:

[image]

> Web gear holds extra ammunition

Most likely the ammo is for the Sonn-Blas FWMB-10 megablaster (a.k.a. "big frigging gun") our friend is holding in the image above.

Comment: Bonus points if you can figure out how the ammo is actually supposed to fit into the gun.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I'm not totally sure, but there looks like an ammo slot just in front of the trigger. I'll keep looking

Comment: Maybe the white part is just a box, and the actual ammo clip is *inside?*